# Unable to get images from internal memory in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Pics/");
if (!file.exists()) {
   file.mkdirs();
}
File[] pictures = file.listFiles();
```

file exists returns true but pictures returns null

Comment: Are there any files in the folder?

Comment: yes it has some images

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory()` will return the root of an `SD Card` if present. Are you sire, you are looking at the right place?

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Pics is the returned value

Comment: did you ask for permissions?

Comment: Remove the last "/" after `Pics` in your new file

Comment: permission also specified and removed "/" still not working

Answer (score 1):

Use a ContentResolver to find the images.

```
    Uri photo = data.getData();
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
       Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(photo, projection, null, null, null);
       int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
       cursor.moveToFirst();

       textureName = cursor.getString(column_index);

       try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(textureName);


       } catch (IOException ioEx) {
               ioEx.printStackTrace();
       }
```